# $|\vec{a}| = 2 \sqrt{3}.$ If angle $\vec{a}$ same with $\vec{b}$ or $\vec{c}$, and perp with $\vec{d}$, what is $\vec{a}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

$$ \vec{b} = <y, -2z, 3x>, \vec{c} = <2z, 3x, -y> $$

It is known that $\vec{a}$ forms an obtuse angle wrt the $y$ axis and $|\vec{a}| = 2 \sqrt{3}.$ If $\vec{a}$ forms the same angle with $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, and perpendicular with $\vec{d} = <1,-1,2>$, what is $\vec{a}$?

---

**Attempt:**

I suspect some mistype in the problem, this is a problem from an entrance Exam of a university (undergraduate level).

If I am not mistaken we cannot have $x,y,z$ in the vector, unless there is a terminology pertaining to this that I don't know.

So I presume that $\vec{b} = <B, -2C, 3A>, \vec{c} = <2C, 3A, -B>$.

Now from the info of $\vec{a}$ we get
$$ a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} + a_{3}^{2} = 12$$
and 
$$ a_{1} - a_{2} + 2 a_{3} = 0 $$

It is also said that, using rule $\frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|} = \cos(\theta)$, we get

$$ a_{1}B - 2a_{2}C + 3a_{3}A = 2a_{1}C + 3a_{2}A - a_{3}B $$
or 
$$ 3(a_{2} - a_{3})A  -(a_{3} + a_{1})B + 2(a_{2} + a_{1})C = 0$$

then we must have

$a_{2} =a_{3}$, $a_{3} = -a_{1}$, $a_{2} = -a_{1}$.

In the end we must have $a_{1}=  \pm 2$, and to find unique $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ we must check that $ \frac{\vec{a} \cdot <0, 1, 0>}{2\sqrt{3}} < 0$ because the angle must be $ 90 < \theta \le 180 $. Am I interpreting this correctly?

If so the answer is $\vec{a} = <2,-2,-2>$

Comment: "Because $A,B,C$ arbitrary then we must have..." Are $A, B, C$ arbitrary? Are they not just unknown, fixed quantities?

Comment: @TheoBendit the problem does not specify that, so I presume. The problem use $x,y,z$, but it also says $y$ is an axis.

Comment: I suspect you're right and you're interpreting the problem correctly, but the problem could definitely be more clear.

Comment: @TheoBendit This is a multiple choice problem btw. And there is $<2,-2,-2>$. All other options does not satisfy both the perpendicular and the $|\vec{a}|=2\sqrt{3}$.